# Is there a way to keep only those variables with a certain label?

Tags: stata

I have a very large dataset that needs to be refined to only certain variables. These variables' names are all over the place, but each wanted variable's label starts with "AW". Is there a way to use `keep` or an analogous command to keep only these variables?

Answer (score 2):

For this you probably need a loop.

```
// create sample data
clear
set obs 1
generate x = 1
generate y = 2
generate z = 3
label variable x "AW test"
label variable y "XW test"
label variable z "AQ test"
describe

// do the job
foreach var of varlist x-z {
    local lbl : variable label `var'
    if substr("`lbl'",1,2)!="AW" drop `var'
    }
describe
```

The second `describe` will show that only the variable x remains.

Answer (score 1):

Official command `ds` and user-written command `findname` (*Stata Journal*: use `search findname` to download latest version) will identify such variables, after which `keep` can be used directly.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. d

Contains data from C:\Program Files\Stata10\ado\base/a/auto.dta
  obs:            74                          1978 Automobile Data
 vars:            12                          13 Apr 2007 17:45
 size:         3,478 (99.9% of memory free)   (_dta has notes)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage  display     value
variable name   type   format      label      variable label
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
make            str18  %-18s                  Make and Model
price           int    %8.0gc                 Price
mpg             int    %8.0g                  Mileage (mpg)
rep78           int    %8.0g                  Repair Record 1978
headroom        float  %6.1f                  Headroom (in.)
trunk           int    %8.0g                  Trunk space (cu. ft.)
weight          int    %8.0gc                 Weight (lbs.)
length          int    %8.0g                  Length (in.)
turn            int    %8.0g                  Turn Circle (ft.)
displacement    int    %8.0g                  Displacement (cu. in.)
gear_ratio      float  %6.2f                  Gear Ratio
foreign         byte   %8.0g       origin     Car type
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:  foreign

. ds, has(varlabel Mile*)
mpg

. findname , varlabeltext(Mile*)
mpg

. keep `r(varlist)'

. d

Contains data from C:\Program Files\Stata10\ado\base/a/auto.dta
  obs:            74                          1978 Automobile Data
 vars:             1                          13 Apr 2007 17:45
 size:           444 (99.9% of memory free)   (_dta has notes)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage  display     value
variable name   type   format      label      variable label
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpg             int    %8.0g                  Mileage (mpg)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:  
     Note:  dataset has changed since last saved
```